# How to automatically update database after regular time intervals in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, background-process

I want to automatically update my database after regular time intervals, what will be more suitable process to do this task ? My project is in ASP.net MVC.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look on quartz.net. It is a library for such tasks. Tutorial is on http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

Could take a look at webbackgrounder https://github.com/NuGet/WebBackgrounder

Very basic and simple task runner. Check the related nuget packages. For anything complex use quartz.net.